# Cannot convert string to long

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, converters, numberformatexception

Whenever the getAsString function is called of timeConverter I am getting number format exception at line `long timeMillis=Long.parseLong(time);` I want to convert the given string to long.

1) Here is my timeConverter class

```
package com.converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;

public class TimeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        return arg2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        System.out.println("inside getAsString");
        String time=value.toString();

        long timeMillis=Long.parseLong(time);
        long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        long eclapseTime=timeMillis-currentTime;
        long secs=eclapseTime/1000;
        long days=secs/(60*60*24);
        long hours=(secs%(60*60*24))/60*60;
        long mins=(secs%(60*60*24)%(60*60))/60;
        long secs2=(secs%(60*60*24)%(60*60)%(60));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(days).append("days").append(hours).append("hours").append(mins).append("mins").append(secs2).append("secs");
        String object = sb.toString();
        return object;

    }

}
```

2) Here is stackstrace that I am getting.

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1348756490255"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at com.converter.TimeConverter.getAsString(TimeConverter.java:37)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getFormattedValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:519)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getFormattedValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:538)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:357)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Where is your `value` coming from?? Where are you calling your method?

Comment: the value is comming from <h:outputText value="#{p.timeMillis}"/> in xhtml page.

Comment: Strange, stack says you are trying to parse your string into an integer and in code you appear to be trying to parse it to long !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1348756490255"
...
  java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
```

Which means it's too long for integer. Max value for Integer is 2 147 483 647, so it fails on 134 875 649 025, which makes sense.

However, you're claiming that you're having the problem with this code:

```
long timeMillis=Long.parseLong(time);
```

which clearly isn't true, as per stack trace. Conclusion is that you're running a different code than you think you're running - parsing the string as long should work without issues. Long has a max value of 9 223 372 036 854 775 807 which is a lot more than you need.

Comment: yeah, I will second that. I tried, no problem while parsing that string to long

Comment: yup its running properly now. Sorry for the wrong stackstrace.

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace says you're using `Integer.parseInt(...)` rather than `Long.parseLong(...)`. The number in the error message, `"1348756490255"` is much bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`2147483647`).

It also says that the error occurs on line 37 of `TimeConverter.java`, and the source code you give doesn't even have 37 lines. You may have forgotten to both save in the editor and then recompile.

As a small aside, don't use `StringBuffer`s. The Java compiler will convert `String` concatenations using `+` to use `StringBuffer` behind the scenes automatically.

Comment: I agree about not using StringBuffer, but for a different reason: StringBuilder is the one that should be used in this case (and in almost all of the cases StringBuffer was used in the past). Java compiler can and usually does make the optimization, but it is also possible that it does not do it.